# Can't understand how Griffiths derives an expression in QM text

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions

I am just dumb, as he provides the equations he uses (highlighted) but I just want to know how he is getting the final expression in 3.31?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This just uses the definition of the delta function in 2.144, since:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dke^{ikx}=2\pi\delta(x)\to \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx e^{i(p-p')x/\hbar}=2\pi\delta\left(\frac{p-p'}{\hbar}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Now, since $\hbar$ is a real constant, use Eq.2.142 to arrive at the rhs of 3.31; note that $c$ in Eq.2.142 is just your $\frac{1}{\hbar}$ above, so
\begin{eqnarray}
\delta\left(\frac{p-p'}{\hbar}\right)=\frac{\delta\left(p-p'\right)}{|\frac{1}{\hbar}|}=\hbar\delta(p-p').
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: The RHS is using exactly the same expression as the LHS: the only difference is that on the RHS, your variable of integration is $x$ rather than $k$ (that is why the result of the integral must be a function independent of $x$). On the LHS, you integrate in $k$, and that gives you a delta function in $x$. On the RHS of the arrow, the variable of integration is different, but the integral is exactly of the same functional form.